# How to fix earphone foam

Tags: comfort, headphones

I'm looking for a cheap alternative to the foam earpads that come with earphones, as mine have mostly fallen apart. I need some ideas or experiences from users to be able to do so.

I ordered a pair, but it's too small for my earphones. The company doesn't allow returns or replacements, so I'm unwilling to spend money again, hence a cost effective idea will be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would you mind detailing the condition of your earphones? Perhaps a picture can help

Comment: Please include a close-up picture (as @DarkCygnus requested).

Comment: Well, I am not sure if this may be considered as an anwer, because you mentioned you don't want to spent extra money on it. But did you order correct ones? I see you probably have [Sony MDR G45LP](http://www.sony.co.in/electronics/headband-headphones/mdr-g45lp) earphones. I found on ebay [10 pcs of foams](https://www.ebay.com/itm/10-Pcs-Foam-Ear-Pads-Cushion-Pad-For-Sony-MDR-G45LP-G45-LP-G55LP-G410L-Headphone/162635911040) for only $3.39 its arround $0.34 for a piece. It's quite cost effective in my opinion :)

Comment: I've ordered replacement pads before, and as long as they are specifically for your set, they'll fit regardless of if they seem too small.  They usually require a bit a stretching to fit correctly, and this is by design.

Comment: @computercarguy and running.t I found that although I had ordered the right size, I was delivered a size much smaller. It was for a 5.5 cm earphone, but I got a 3.5 cm ear pad. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Even if the company doesn't allow returns or replacements, it's their mess up, so they should fix it, since they are the ones that sent the wrong product.

Comment: @computercarguy I got myself a replacement the way you told me. Thanks for that! So I believe since this is what worked, should this question be left unanswered? Or should it be deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Based on [my prior comment](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/17858/how-to-fix-earphone-foam/17873#comment25136_17858) which the [OP confirmed](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/17858/how-to-fix-earphone-foam/17873#comment25145_17858) as accepted answer.*

Even if the company doesn't allow returns or replacements, it's their mess up, so they should fix it, since they are the ones that sent the wrong product.

Answer (score 1):

Go get a nice soft sponge, trace/measure the shape of your headphones on a piece of paper, and cut the sponge to make pads.

Then, go online and find Disposable Sanitary Earpiece Covers for Small Headphones that fit your headphones' size. Put the cut shapes of sponge inside the cloth covers and put them on your headphones.

If your existing pads on your headphones are still good, just use the cloth covers now. The cloth covers will make the existing pads last because you can just replace the cloth covers when they get grungy.

[https://www.amazon.com/Disposable-Sanitary-Earpiece-Covers-Headphones/dp/B00C7BXWGO](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C7BXWGO)

A couple of years ago I bought these cloth covers for my large headphones because they were leather. I got tired of cleaning the ear wax off/sweat residue the headphones. And, the leather was uncomfortable in the hot weather.

These cloth covers are cheap. So, I don't mind changing them when they wear out or get a bit used.

Comment: Now that's exactly what I wanted. +1 for a creative answer, but sadly, I've already bought a pair of ear foams... Still, I'd like to try this if I ever need to replace the ones I've bought, e.g. when they get old or whatever.

Comment: I found out about them because the local libraries used them when they had public headphones. I thought they were more comfortable than just using the pads. They are relatively inexpensive.